# Links are of no use on Contact page

Tags: support

I am talking about [Stack Overflow Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/) link.

[image: Contact page screenshot]

These links point to external links of other sites such as Facebook, Google, Yahoo. Those links are **"NOT"** the pages created on external sites by Stack Overflow company. Those links are merely links to help portal of 3rd party sites which are having nothing to do with Stack Overflow.

Now lets consider we are thinking about this like: By going to these links user will be able to search on 3rd party site about **Stack Overflow**.

**1.**

So if it's like this then see what happens after clicking on **"Google contact"** link. When I  search about Stack Overflow on this site like say:

```
 http://www.google.com/contact/  ===> Type stack overflow
```

you will get [this search page](https://www.google.com/search?q=stack%20overflow&output=googleabout&sitesearch=www.google.com&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl):

[image]

which merely contains only one link (first) that points to Stack Overflow. Others have nothing to do with our Stack Overflow site.

**2.**

When I use Yahoo search link and do searching, I get:

[image: Yahoo search link result]

again nothing is related to our Stack Overflow.

**3.**

When I use Facebook search link and do searching, I get:

[image: Facebook search link result]

again nothing is related to our Stack Overflow.

May I know the use of such linking?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> May I know the use of such linking ?

We get a lot of support emails. A lot of them are actually for Facebook/Yahoo!/Google and have nothing to do with Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. Nothing.

The links are there for people who end up on the contact page but have an issue that has **nothing** to do with the site. It gives them a link to the place where they **do** have an issue.

Having the links there has reduces the amount of noise in our support email.

Comment: I really don't understand Why would someone come on **contact page** of stackoverflow and search for content he would find regarding Facebook.com, Google.com, Yahoo.com ? **:)**. Isn't it funny?

Comment: We don't understand that either. **But they do**.

Comment: StackOverflow sounds like something coding related, right?! It's coders, SURELY they can fix ANY website! I mean, don't lie, you know how non tech people see our knowledge....